# Transfer control with inline buttons in telegram (bots)

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook, node-telegram-bot-api

If you have a bot-generated in-line button in a chat, that inline button can be used to take you to a bot.

My question is - is the reverse possible?

Can the bot have an inline button (when directly communicating with it) and it can transfer control to a group where the user and bot are both present

Consider this scenario:
I have a bot that track country names. When added to a group it detects a country name and says “see information about the country”.

When you click the button, the bot takes you to a chat with it (changes wondows and moves you out)  and then the bot displays information about the country.

The bot then has a “go back or cancel” inline button.

If you click that button, it should take you BACK to the originating group you came from. Is that possible?

Variation:

Can it move you back to the originating group automatically (without an inline button) but say based on some text you type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I got is you wanna to take back your users to their refer place right?

For example you have **"Back"** button in your channel. If user came from **Channel A** you want to detect that when it clicks on **Back** button you want to take it back to **Channel A**.
No it's not possible. Telegram bots can't track user activity like this. But Telegram do itself. For example if you visit some channels like this:

> Channel A => First Post => Go to another channel (Channel B) => Then go to admin profile

If you click Back button triple time you will go to first step which in this case is **Channel A**

Bot if your bot is in one private group or private channel you can get the link of every message because Telegram added this feature [here](https://telegram.org/blog/archive-and-new-design#easier-forwarding-links-to-messages-online-badges) :

> you can now copy links to messages in private groups and channels – just like you could with public messages.

So if user **mention** your bot's username on any message in private group/channel you can get the link of that message. Here is some example :

```
 {
   "ok": true,
   "result": [{
     "update_id": 954197936,
     "message": {
       "message_id": 188,
       "from": {
         "id": 223110107,
         "is_bot": false,
         "first_name": "Ğąme ",
         "last_name": "Ǿver!",
         "username": "GameO7er",
         "language_code": "en"
       },
       "chat": {
         "id": -1001241538300,
         "title": "Game Over Test Group",
         "type": "supergroup"
       },
       "date": 1576312634,
       "reply_to_message": {
         "message_id": 130,
         "from": {
           "id": 156878147,
           "is_bot": false,
           "first_name": "Carlos F",
           "username": "@Carlos****",
           "language_code": "en"
         },
         "chat": {
           "id": -1001241538300,
           "title": "Game Over Test Group",
           "type": "supergroup"
         },
         "date": 1554783715,
         "text": "Hello Game Over!"
       },
       "text": "@Go***bot",
       "entities": [{
         "offset": 0,
         "length": 10,
         "type": "mention"
       }]
     }
   }]
 }
```

The link of this message is:

> **https://t.me/c/1241538300/130**

As you can see it will be generate from **chat id**

```
 "chat": {
         "id": -1001241538300,
         "title": "Game Over Test Group",
         "type": "supergroup"
       },
```

remove **`-100`** from **`-1001241538300`** then you have **`1241538300`** and contact **`/c/message_id`** to end of it.

```
"date": 1576312634,
       "reply_to_message": {
         "message_id": 130,
         "from": {
           "id": 156878147,
           "is_bot": false,
           "first_name": "Carlos F",
           "username": "@Carlos****",
           "language_code": "en"
         },
```

and you will have :

> **https://t.me/c/1241538300/130**